# Converting number to hours?

Tags: javascript

Hello I have this using javascript :

```
var newhour = 20.5;
hour.setHours(newhour);
```

The problem is when I do `console.log(hour)` I get `20:05` but I would like to get `20:30`.

How can I do this ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: 8 = 20 in european time @sp00m

Comment: I mean i sort of get the question. 8pm = 20pm and 0.5 should be 30 minutes instead of 5 minutes. @sp00m'

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert `0.5` into the number of minutes:

```js
var newhour = 20.5;

var hour = new Date();

var newhours = Math.floor(newhour),
    newmins  = 60 * (newhour - newhours);

hour.setHours(newhours);
hour.setMinutes(newmins);

console.log(hour.toTimeString());
```

Comment: Or you can just set `newmins  = 60 * newhour;` and `hour.setHours(0);
hour.setMinutes(newmins);`

Comment: I'd prefer `Math.floor` instead of that string / parseInt stuff

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @JonasWilms - I agree it's a better solution. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the hours, minutes and seconds by getting only the parts for the units.

```js
function setTime(date, time) {
    ['setHours', 'setMinutes', 'setSeconds']
        .reduce((t, k) => (date[k](Math.floor(t)), t % 1 * 60), time);
}

var hour = new Date,
    newhour = 8.5;

setTime(hour, newhour);

console.log(hour);
```

Comment: Nice one, I would just wrap this into a function, so that the original `newhour` doesn't get reassigned.

Comment: overengineering. Still like this though.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to get `20:30`

To set the time to exactly `20:30:00.000` from `newhour = 20.5`, you would take advantage of `setHours()` having four (optional) arguments ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)). Simply convert `newhour` to milliseconds (multiply by `3600000`), and pass as fourth argument:

```js
hour.setHours(0, 0, 0, 20.5 * 36e5);
```

Demo code here:

```js
var someDate = new Date;
var newHour  = 20.5;

someDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, newHour * 36e5);

console.log(someDate.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [momentjs duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) for that:

```js
const duration = moment.duration(20.5, 'hours')
console.log(duration.hours() + ':' + duration.minutes());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```